# imagemagick check if image is of almost one single color

Tags: imagemagick

Friends,

I have a stack of color-scanned images. Some are from regular white paper with text or images, others were scanned from colored paper (blank pages, same green colored paper used.)

I'd like to identify these colored paper images. Problems:

1. paper's color ("background") is not scanned very uniformly, often has a wavy or structured pattern
2. green tone is quite different depending on the scanner used
3. scanner does not catch the full sheet resulting in a white or shadowed "border" around green area

My idea was to see if say 90% of the image is some sort of green and tried using a sorted histogram. But because of (1) and esp. (2) I have a hard time picking a working color value from the histogram data.

Any help appreciated!

Edit:
Here are three sample images, scanned from the same sheet of paper.
[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Representative images for the various cases would help...

Comment: These are just everyday pages like letters and invoices and a blue page scanned from a  empty blue sheet of paper. I could produce examples of these if that really helps.

Although I think I have seen SO answers with images I cannot find any "upload image" option. I guess I need additional reputation for this, do I?

Comment: It's a picture icon just to the right of **Bold** and *Italic* in the formatting bar if you click [edit].

Comment: Thanks Mark, didn't notice I could edit my post. Images added.

Comment: That's better but it's still not clear what you are trying to do. You say you want to identify the coloured sheets - but they are all coloured sheets. You say that different scanners and lighting are causing problems but a coloured sheet is a coloured sheet even if one scanner thinks the colour is rgb(78, 43, 192) and another scanner makes it rgb(83, 39, 200), surely? And why are the shadows an issue, surely you can crop 10-15% off all edges before testing, or are the shadows not really at the edges. Just trying to understand...

Comment: Might they be red? If not, you can convert to HSV, extract the hue channel and get the average of the hue channel. If not red, then any hue=0 average would be white/gray/black. You can then test the Value channel to see if dark (black) or bright (white).

Comment: @mark exactly, these are colored pages with varying rgb values of green. The question is: how do I check "is this one of these greenish pages" with imagemagick? All other pages are just with text, logo, images pages on white background, I do not need to identify these as I like to keep them. I see if I can get a sample for you that does not have sensitiy information on it I could not publish but as said I do not need to identify these as long as I identifing the green ones.

Comment: @fmw42 The process you suggested looks promising - how would I do that? (If easier to identify we might be able to use blue or yellow paper.)

Comment: So you merely want to know if they are greenish, not what shade of green, not if they have writing?

Comment: @mark yes exactly. Just "is it greenish". There will be no text on them anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at HSV colourspace on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) - specifically [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#/media/File:HSL-HSV_hue_and_chroma.svg) diagram.

It should be a better place to find the colour of your images, regardless of scanner and calibration.

Now, let's create a lime-green, yellow and cyan block and derive its colour using **ImageMagick**:

```
magick -size 100x100 xc:lime -colorspace HSV -channel 0 -separate -format "%[fx:mean*360]" info:
120

magick -size 100x100 xc:yellow -colorspace HSV -channel 0 -separate -format "%[fx:mean*360]" info:
60
                                                                                                                                  
magick -size 100x100 xc:magenta -colorspace HSV -channel 0 -separate -format "%[fx:mean*360]" info:
300
                                                                                                                                                                 
magick -size 100x100 xc:cyan -colorspace HSV -channel 0 -separate -format "%[fx:mean*360]" info:
180
```

Hopefully you can see we are correctly calculating the Hue angle. Now to your image. I have added an artificial frame so you can see how to remove the edges:

[image]

We can remove the frame like this:

```
magick YOURSCAN.jpg -gravity center -crop 80% cropped.jpg
```

[image]

---

So, my complete suggestion would be to crop and convert to HSV and check the mean Hue. You could also test if the image is fairly saturated so it doesn't pick up grey-ish, uncoloured images. You could also test the variance in the Hue channel to see if there are many different colours - or the spread of the hues is large and reject ones where it is large.

```
magick YOURSCAN.jpg -gravity center -crop 80% -colorspace HSV -channel 0 -separate -format "%[fx:mean*360]" info:
```

---

Just for reference, your 3 images come up with the following Hue angles on a scale of 0..360:

```
79, 68, 73
```

I would suggest you test a few more samples to establish a reasonable range.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Works like a charm. Note: For testing, I created fake red, blue and grey images from the above and also checked the regular text scans as well. Image 1 from above converted to greyscale results in 0, red is between 6 and 45, blue above 220 and regular text pages on white paper are between 7 and 21. That's an easy to handle number range. Perfect!